# Unable to set up handlebars due to : TypeError: handlebars is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, handlebars.js

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

//set up handlebars
const handlebars = require('express-handlebars');
app.engine("handlebars",handlebars())
app.set("view engine", "handlebars")


const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3');
const sqlite = require('sqlite');

const port = 8080

const dbPromise = sqlite.open({

    filename:"./database/sakila.sqlite",
    driver: sqlite3.Database
})


app.get("/",(req,res)=>{

  
    res.render("home",{layout:false});

})


app.listen(port,()=>{

    console.log(`server running on ${port}`);


})
```

I was following a lecture video to learn about handlebars. I typed the same code word by word to set up handlebars and I did npm install express-handlebars --save. The instructor's code is working but mine is not.
It only warns me that

"app.engine("handlebars",handlebars())
^

TypeError: handlebars is not a function

"
I couldn't figure out why. Please help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Simply read [the documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-handlebars), which says : `import { engine } from 'express-handlebars'; app.engine('handlebars', engine())`. I assume you can also use `app.engine("handlebars",handlebars.engine())`

Answer (score 1):

```
const express = require("express");
const handlebars = require("express-handlebars");
const app = express();

//set up handlebars

app.engine("handlebars", handlebars());
app.set("view engine", "handlebars");

const sqlite3 = require("sqlite3");
const sqlite = require("sqlite");

const port = 8080;

const dbPromise = sqlite.open({
  filename: "./database/sakila.sqlite",
  driver: sqlite3.Database
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", { layout: false });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`server running on ${port}`);
});
```